# Variation on Descartes' famous phrase

Tags: philosophy-terms

I would like to put a twist on Descartes' famous phrase, "Cogito, ergo sum".

Effectively I want to say, "I am... I think?", raising the question of whether the existence we perceive with our senses is the truth of reality, and in exploring that: whether Descartes' position is still a valid argument.

So would it be correct to say "Ego sum... cogito?" and if not, how would you phrase it in Latin?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think your translation would be understandable, and the resemblance to the original justifies the possible lack of grammatical correctness. I'm not sure if _cogito_ is the verb to express this kind of belief (I'd use [puto](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dputo) or [credo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcredo) instead). In Latin you usually express beliefs with the infinitive: **puto me esse**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Cogito, ergo sum – quod sciam* (“...as far as I know,”
made famous by Winnie ille Pu).

Comment: I guess that's as close as it gets, thanks (doesn't that mean I KNOW THAT, though?). Anyway, I'm marking as answered until something better comes along :-)

Comment: Dear Riegardt, ‘quod sciam’ means something like “as far as I know” (quod sciam). Vale.